# Verify items on bootstrap modal in protractor test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, bootstrap-modal

I need to check the text in a div which is in a bootstrap modal window. The expected message is 'Password is required' but I am getting ''. The test is passing sometimes and sometimes not. I have tried browser.wait(), getWindowHandles() to solve this problem, but those didn't work.

Both of my window is angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `browser.wait()` and the [`textToBePresentInElement` expected condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElement):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions, 
    elm = element(by.css("[ng-message=required]"));
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(elm, "Password is required"), 5000);
expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: @NasrinhakimMithila okay, could you show the HTML representation of the element? Thanks.

Comment: <div
      ng-if="submitted"
      class="error-message" >
    <div ng-message="required">Password is required.</div>                     </div>

Comment: @NasrinhakimMithila thanks, updated the answer, see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still got the time out error. Well one more thing, I think I have some focus issue, because the tests pass when the browser window is in focus, but fail otherwise.